# Quicktag insert multiple lines

Tags: quicktag

I use the Editor Quicktag Buttons to store special things like this example below is used to store the DIV's to make Columns on my theme.

I need help, I want to modify the snippet below so that it will insert the HTML onto multiple lines, so instead of adding

```
<div class="one-half first">1st</div>n/<div class="one-half">2nd</div>n\<div class="clear-line"></div>
```

To the textarea as one Line, I would like to insert it as 3 lines like this...

```
<div class="one-half first">1st</div>
<div class="one-half">2nd</div>
<div class="clear-line"></div>
```

Here is the code I use to add this button...

```
QTags.addButton( 'columns', 'Columns', '<div class="one-half first">1st</div>n/<div class="one-half">2nd</div>n\<div class="clear-line"></div>', '' );
```

Comment: What have you tried already? What happened then? Why do you think that is a WP question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the format you need to follow,

```
//double quotes require escaping
var your_html = "<div class=\"one-half first\">1st</div>\n<div class=\"one-half\">2nd</div>\n<div class=\"clear-line\"></div>";

//single quotes do not require escpaing
var your_html = '<div class="one-half first">1st</div>\n<div class="one-half">2nd</div>\n<div class="clear-line"></div>';

QTags.addButton( 'my_tag', 'Multi Line', your_html, '' );
```

I'd just store my html in a var (eg. `your_html`) then pass that to your `QTags.addButton`

You can also do,

```
var more_html = [
'<div class="one-half first">1st</div>\n',
'<div class="etc">etc</div>\n',
'<div class="etc etc">etc etc</div>'
].join('');

QTags.addButton( 'my_tag_again', 'More Multi Line', more_html, '');
```

Even though this is related to WordPress, **its not a WordPress question**, technically, because the problem entirely focuses on JavaScript in which is always better served as a question over at [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

But since I'm at it, there's your answer.

I personally use the second syntax above which is easier to read and make sense of long strings, especially HTML.